# ImportError: No module named ui_imagedialog

Tags: pyqt4, qt-designer

I  am new to pyQt4. First I installed pyqt4 then installed QTDesigner. And tried to run the given program( From internet). The file is named as main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QDialog
from ui_imagedialog import Ui_ImageDialog
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QDialog()
ui = Ui_ImageDialog()
ui.setupUi(window)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

run the program using terminal

```
python main.py
```

I got the following error

```
from ui_imagedialog import Ui_ImageDialog
ImportError: No module named ui_imagedialog
```

How to solve this??

Comment: This is because you downloaded the `main.py` but you forgot to download `ui_imagedialog.py`

Comment: no the problem is that.. the file should be save as .ui extension  and i got the gui

Answer (score 2):

You could try running this instead;

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QDialog
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QDialog()

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And if you are using PyQt5, use this;

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QDialog()

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This will produce an empty window.
From the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), the **ui_imagedialog** is an imaginary file.